# Archlinux kernel Заморозка ядра

Tags: kernel, archlinux

Если заморозить пакеты linux, `linux-api-headers`, `linux-headers` на определённую версию, не будет проблем с остальными постоянно обновляющимися пакетами?

Comment: есть пара пакетов, которые зависят от ядра - libc/glibc. То есть, они обычно хотят версию ядра "не ниже определенной". А от libc/glibc зависит очень много пакетов. Отсюдова и делайте выводы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, если у них нет зависимостей от этих пакетов. Но даже если и есть - то такие пакеты просто тоже не должны обновиться, всего лишь.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас стоят модули Nvidia, то они могут или явно затребовать при обновлении какую-то версию ядра, или просто криво работать с более старыми версиями.